# Can you alter the output of %caller{0} in logback to mimic log4j %l specifier?

Tags: log4j, logback

I am migrating to Logback from log4j. Log4j has the %l format specifier which will print out the fully qualified name of the calling method followed by the callers source the file name and line number between parentheses. Example: com.my.company.MyClass.doSomething(MyClass.java:54)

I want the same output using Logback. They don't have the %l format specified. They do have the %caller format specifier and when you provide the {0} option you will get the first level of the call stack. Example: Caller+0     at com.my.company.MyClass.doSomething(MyClass.java:54)

I don't want the prefix "Caller+0     at ". Is there a way to do this without having to create my own format specifier in which I would just remove that part of the string?

Comment: and it make a new line too. Did you solve it?

Comment: [I have just added a new feature request for this here](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1096)

Answer (score 0):

try the following command in your compiling

```
javac -g
```