# Logback pattern equivalent of log4j %l

Tags: java, logging, log4j, logback

Configuring log4j I can use the [log4j 1.2 pattern](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) `%l` to give me location of the caller, which outputs:

```
... com.example.FooBar.doSomething(FooBar.java:123) ...
```

I'm trying to switch to Logger because it is ["intended as a successor"](http://logback.qos.ch/) to log4j and has [all sorts of improvements](http://logback.qos.ch/reasonsToSwitch.html) over log4j 1.2

But Logback has no `%l` pattern. The closest [Logback pattern](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) I can find is `%caller{1}`, but that gives me something ugly:

```
... Caller+0     at com.example.FooBar.doSomething(FooBar.java:123)
...
```

Notice that, adding insult to ugly, it adds a newline in the middle of my log line. (I did not specify a newline in the pattern at that point.)

How do I get the equivalent of log4j `%l` in my Logback pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As durron597 indicated, a single conversion variable that is the exact replacement for log4j `%l` does not seem to be available. But by combining several conversion variables one can achieve the same effect.

Specifically replace every instance of `%l` in your log4j configuration with the following for Logback: `%class.%method\(%file:%line\)`

(If you are doing this programmatically, make sure to double the backslashes as required for Java strings.)

Several of these variables are indicated as degrading the performance of the application. I've looked at the source code, though, and at least the relevant information is cached so that using multiple slow conversion variables in the pattern should not be any worse performance than using just one.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `%l` no longer exists in logback. This is probably because, from your own documentation link:

> The location information can be very useful. However, its generation is **extremely slow** and should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.

Unfortunately, you can't do much better with `%caller`, even though you are correct that it is the best substitute for `%l`. As you can see [in the source here](http://logback.qos.ch/xref/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/CallerDataConverter.html#L159), that newline is pretty thoroughly embedded in the error message generation step.

I wish I had better news for you, but I don't think you're going to be able to do better without a [custom `Layout`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#writingYourOwnLayout). You can take some small comfort in the fact that [this has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686432/can-you-alter-the-output-of-caller0-in-logback-to-mimic-log4j-l-specifier).

---

I have [just submitted a new Feature Request here.](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-1096)

Comment: I guess this is the right answer, even though I don't like it. But your JIRA ticket shouldn't be "minor" --- this may prevent my client from going with Logback, even though it is supposedly better than log4j. And a tip: in JIRA, add \ to escape the braces so that they aren't interpreted incorrectly in the description. Lastly, thanks for taking the time to investigate this and file an issue with Logback.

Comment: By the way, you should indicate in your quote which documentation you're referring to. You copied from the _log4j_ documentation for `%l`. But Logback has no similar wording for `%caller`, and all I want is the `%caller` information formatted better. (Perhaps it does affect performance; but we don't know that from the Logback documentation.) I would say this is a bug, not a feature request --- regardless of performance or JVM differences, I didn't ask for a newline and I don't expect to get one when logging a single string in the pattern.

Comment: Again durron597 I appreciate your help. But I just reread my question and realized it was how to get the equivalent of log4j `%l` on Logback. So I'll answer my own question separately with this information.

Comment: @GarretWilson I looked at the source code for both log4j and logback; this is a non trivial chance for logback, I would have made a pull request not a JIRA case if it were easy.

Comment: Also major bugs are for things like crashes, as much as you want this feature it doesn't meet the internal definition of "major" on the Logback team. The same is true of the "feature request" vs bug issue.

Comment: Regarding being "non trivial", it looks easy enough to me. See my separate answer. If I can piece them together in the pattern string, there should be no reason why there couldn't be a `Converter` keyed to "l" that simply delegates to the other converters. Lastly, I could live with `%caller{1}` if it it didn't have a tab and a newline. I don't see why it would be so hard for `CallerDataConverter` to forego a tab and newline (lines 157 and 159) if the limit results in a single line. So many easy ways to do this in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [replace](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#replace) conversion word. The following regex removes the unwanted Caller and extra new line:

```
%replace(%caller{1}){'Caller\+0\s*at\s*([^\n]*)\n', '$1'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `CallerDataConverter` and override the `convert` to strip of the line separator. `PatternLayout` exposes a static map of converters. You can update this map with your converter as part of bootstrap, better to do in some class initialization static block. Not beautiful but should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just modified few things in above verified answer,

`%logger{50}.%M\\(%file:%line\\)`

(As per the doc) For xml configuration, Even though If I try adding One backslash `\` infront of parenthesis, not working, Try add double backslash,