# Get logger by name, print class name

Tags: java, logging, logback, slf4j

I want to grab a logger by it's name as I have multiple loggers, but still print the class name of the class which is logging the message. Appreciate the assistance.

Example:

```
<!--Loggers...-->
<logger name="LoggerA"><appender-ref="AppenderA"></appender></logger>
<logger name="LoggerB"><appender-ref="AppenderB"></appender></logger>
<logger name="LoggerC"><appender-ref="AppenderC"></appender></logger>
```

Assume that each of these loggers will write to a different `*.log` file.

```
<<From ClassXYZ>>
private static final Logger LOGA = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LoggerA");
private static final Logger LOGB = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LoggerB");
private static final Logger LOGC = LoggerFactory.getLogger("LoggerC");
```

Within each file, there will be the following statements:

```
2017-04-06 18:23:12,538 [main] [] INFO  LoggerA - <<Some Log Message>>

2017-04-06 18:23:12,538 [main] [] INFO  LoggerB - <<Some Log Message>>

2017-04-06 18:23:12,538 [main] [] INFO  LoggerC - <<Some Log Message>>
```

However I would expect/want for it to be logged as:

```
2017-04-06 18:23:12,538 [main] [] INFO  ClassXYZ - <<Some Log Message>>

2017-04-06 18:23:12,538 [main] [] INFO  ClassXYZ - <<Some Log Message>>

2017-04-06 18:23:12,538 [main] [] INFO  ClassXYZ - <<Some Log Message>>
```

My pattern is:

```
%d [%thread] [%X{CONTEXT}] %-5level %logger{70} - %msg%n
```

Comment: is this working for you private static final Logger LOGA = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassXYZ.class); ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use %l in your pattern, if not mind print code number along with the class name.

ps, %l is a log4j config, if you are using logback, may refer to [Logback pattern equivalent of log4j %l](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32158409/logback-pattern-equivalent-of-log4j-l)